# How do I force a button click on a UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uialertview

In an iOS application that I am coding I am displaying a `UIAlertView` to ask the user for a password and I am trying to allow them to hit enter in the text field to submit the password.

I have handled the enter from the text field in a `textFieldShouldReturn` function. The problem is in the examples I have found online which say to use the `dismissWithClickedButton` method to handle the button click.

When I try this it simply dismisses the `UIAlertView` without checking the password. I really need the **"OK"** button I have setup to fire so I check the password.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: In `dismissWithClickedButton` If the password is incorrect then re-display the alert

Comment: dimissWithClickedButton is a built in function of UIAlertView. I don't think I can add code to it.

Comment: It's a delegate of UIAlertView. If you don't know what a delegate is, then please check these basics of Objective C, else use it.

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to do this as it may help clarify what you're having an issue with? You mention wanting the UIAlertview to check the password, though you describe it comes up before the password is entered?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delegate` method of `UIAlertViewDelegate`

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Buttons in UIAlertView is stored in an array. So you can find the position of **OK** button

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  if(buttonIndex == 1) //Your OK button
  {
    //Do Stuff
  }
}
```